# How to modify url to get iphone version of facebook page?

Tags: iphone, facebook, safari

I'm creating a facebook page for my application and I want it readable on mobile safari for iPhone, but the normal facebook pages don't show up properly (see attached image) The wall, info, discussion pages don't show up.

I know I can prepend m.facebook to a url to make it the mobile version, but what about the iphone version? touch.facebook seems to redirect to facebook login.

[Facebook http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6f62d603e3.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/6f62d603e3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use [m.facebook.com](http://m.facebook.com/).

Comment: that version isn't quite right for iphone, it doesn't have the tabs like photos or discussions/reviews.